# Redirecting to edit_profile after devise sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I'm trying to get my rails app to redirect to the `edit_profile_path` after sign up through devise, but am having serious problems trying to work out how.  I've spent the past four hours on here trying to find a solution, but can't seem to find the problem.

My current routes.rb:

```
   resources :users, :only => [:index] do
    member do
      get :favourite_users, :favourited_users
    end
    resources :posts
    resources :profiles, only: [:show, :edit] 
  end
```

My RegistrationsController.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_profile_path(resource)
  end
end
```

My profile/edit.html.erb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  before_create :build_profile #creates profile at user registration  

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

end
```

My profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    def name
        first_name + " " + last_name[0]
    end
end
```

My ProfilesController.rb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @profile = Profile.new
    end

    def show
    end

    def profile
    end

    def edit
        @profile = current_user.profile
    end
end
```

I've tried as many solutions as I can but all I seem to get is:

```
undefined method `profile_path' for #<#<Class:0xb50b8618>:0xb50abe54>
```

or if I remove the (resources) from the edit_profile_path(resource) in the RegistrationsController:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running the following from console:

```
rake routes
```

This will output all of the routes your app knows about. I'm hoping I read your routes file right (hard to look at without the formatting), but with it being a nested route, I think you actually want to use

```
edit_user_profile_path(resource)
```

Comment: I tried this before and all I got was this: `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles", :user_id=>#<User id: 30,... :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`.  Rake routes shows that the route I have is `edit_profile` (profiles#edit), hence why I was using `edit_profile_path`.  Is that any help?

Comment: Sorry I read it wrong initially. Do you want users to have just one profile or multiple profiles? If you want a user to have just one profile, you'll want to update your routes to say 'resource profile' instead of 'resources profiles'. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources. The edit_user_profile_path(resource) should work after that.

Comment: Ah great!  I also had to change the profile.html.erb top line to `<%= bootstrap_form_for @profile, url: edit_user_profile_path do |f| %>` having read the link you added.  It now works, thanks!